# Conditional Windows Function on a series

Tags: sql, oracle, hive

I'm struggling with getting the average of a series (streak) order by date.. it will be easier to show you directly:

| Login | Week_date | Active_Streak | Inactive_Streak | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2022/01/19 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| abc | 2022/01/25 | 2 | 0 | 6 |
| abc | 2022/02/01 | 3 | 0 | 9 |
| abc | 2022/02/08 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| abc | 2022/02/15 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| abc | 2022/02/22 | 1 | 0 | 6 |
| abc | 2022/03/01 | 2 | 0 | 11 |
| abc | 2022/03/08 | 0 | 1 | NULL |
| abc | 2022/03/15 | 0 | 2 | NULL |
| abc | 2022/01/22 | 1 | 0 | 4 |

I want to know for example the average of the amount, to understand why I had a inactive week and so on for all the time we got an inactive week.

Like one row per inactive week with the average amount and the `week_date`.

I need to get something like this as output:

| Login | Week_date | Active_Streak | Inactive_Streak | AVG_active_Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2022/02/15 | 4 | 1 | 5.25 |
| abc | 2022/03/15 | 2 | 2 | 8.5 |

Comment: What database is this for? Please specify as "sql" isn't enough to tell what syntax to use. e.g. is it MySQL, MS SQL Server? Oracle? - also -  why is 2022/03/08 skipped over in the result? (i.e. what is the logic, please explain that)

Comment: A week_date is a date. Do you mean you want to interpret week_date as week ? and compute avg per week ? How can you compute AVG_active_account as Account is null for both 2022/02/15 and 2022/03/15. can you explain more pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic for selecting just the 2 rows shown in the question isn't explained, but it seems to be when the active streak is 0, but also that the next active streak isn't zero (or NULL). So with that logic in mind I can calculate date ranges, and once those are determined I can locate the rows within those date boundaries to calculate the aggregations:

```
WITH cte1
AS (
    SELECT LOGIN
        , Week_date
        , Active_Streak
        , Inactive_Streak
        , Amount
        , LEAD(Active_Streak) OVER (
            PARTITION BY LOGIN ORDER BY Week_date
            ) AS Next_Active_Streak
        , MIN(Week_date) OVER () AS min_date
    FROM your_table_name
    )
    , cte2
AS (
    SELECT LOGIN
        , COALESCE(LAG(Week_date) OVER (
                PARTITION BY LOGIN ORDER BY Week_date
                ), min_date) AS From_Date
        , Week_date
        , inactive_Streak
    FROM cte1
    WHERE Active_Streak = 0
        AND Inactive_Streak > 0
        AND (
            Next_Active_Streak <> 0
            OR Next_Active_Streak IS NULL
            )
    )
SELECT cte2.LOGIN
    , cte2.week_date
    , MAX(t.Active_Streak) Active_Streak
    , MAX(cte2.inactive_Streak) inactive_Streak
    , AVG(t.amount) AS avg_amount
FROM cte2
LEFT JOIN your_table_name AS t ON cte2.LOGIN = t.LOGIN
    AND t.week_date > cte2.from_date AND t.week_date < cte2.week_date
    AND Amount IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cte2.LOGIN
    , cte2.week_date
```

| LOGIN | week_date | Active_Streak | inactive_Streak | avg_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2022-02-15 | 4 | 1 | 5.2500 |
| abc | 2022-03-15 | 2 | 2 | 8.5000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/COC_pAMz)

Comment: Thats exactly what I had in mind, Thanks its brilliant I wasnt sure it was possible. If I want for example to get the average of all the active week except the last one before the unactive (to understand if I had a drop in amount) I have to add an interval - '7' day in the cte1 for the min(week_date). Correct ?

Comment: Yes you are going to need something like that for the lowest from date. Keep in mind you did not specify which dbms you use so I was reluctant to use date functions as these vary so much. Please don't just use "sql" as the tag. What dbms is it for?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision , I am using Dbeaver on hive (oracle). I had some issues with Jerome s query , when I had multiple login but Paul's query works very well. I am trying to get the average of all the active row EXCEPT the last one before to turn unactive, to compare the data when the player was active versus his last week of activity. I tried to - interval '7' day on the join but doesnt seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: **Dbeaver on hive (oracle)** please add these sorts of facts as tags to your question (I have added hive and oracle already) - but I don't understand the hive/oracle relationship here - can I presume that the query you are after here is being run in Oracle?  These facts are truly important to finding the solution.

Comment: **it did not work** I have to guess what this means, which is that the query operated but produced the wrong results. The generated date ranges do not work "week by week" but as a potentially multi-week units, so introducing a 7 day interval into the join won't produce the desired result. The ONLY date you should need to calculate (or provide manually) is the starting date of the first date range. i.e. see `min_date` in the code provided. Notice how this is used in the second cte to replace a NULL when `LAG(week_date)` is unable to find any row that has a preceding row.

Answer (score 0):

On PostgreSQL, I would do it like that :

```
create table testdata (
Login varchar(50),
Week_date date,
Active_Streak integer,
Inactive_Streak integer,
Amount integer);

insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/01/19', 1, 0, 4);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/01/25', 2, 0, 6);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/02/01', 3, 0, 9);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/02/08', 4, 0, 2);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/02/15', 0, 1, NULL);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/02/22', 1, 0, 6);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/03/01', 2, 0, 11);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/03/08', 0, 1, NULL);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/03/15', 0, 2, NULL);
insert into testdata values ('abc', '2022/01/22', 1, 0, 4);

select * from testdata order by week_date;

 login | week_date  | active_streak | inactive_streak | amount 
-------+------------+---------------+-----------------+--------
 abc   | 2022-01-19 |             1 |               0 |      4
 abc   | 2022-01-22 |             1 |               0 |      4
 abc   | 2022-01-25 |             2 |               0 |      6
 abc   | 2022-02-01 |             3 |               0 |      9
 abc   | 2022-02-08 |             4 |               0 |      2
 abc   | 2022-02-15 |             0 |               1 |   NULL
 abc   | 2022-02-22 |             1 |               0 |      6
 abc   | 2022-03-01 |             2 |               0 |     11
 abc   | 2022-03-08 |             0 |               1 |   NULL
 abc   | 2022-03-15 |             0 |               2 |   NULL
```

and now, the query :

```
with T as (
    select t1.week_date t1date, t1.amount, t2.week_date t2date
    from testdata t1
    left outer join testdata t2
    on t1.week_date < t2.week_date
    where t2.inactive_streak > 0)
select t2date, avg(amount)
from T
where t1date >= (select coalesce(max(t2date), '1901/01/01')
                  from T as x
                  where x.t2date < T.t2date)
group by t2date;
```

it returns :

```
   t2date   |        avg         
------------+--------------------
 2022-02-15 | 5.0000000000000000
 2022-03-08 | 8.5000000000000000
 2022-03-15 |               NULL
```

Comment: Awesome ! thanks a lot everyone I got it !!!